# Specifying destination interface in ping commamd

Tags: ping

is there any way to specify destination interface in ping command, like
`ping  -i eth0(destination interface) host`.
I want to do this so that I can capture packets on host on specific interface specified in ping command.
Thanxx in advance!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to specify destination interface in ping command, like `ping  -i eth0(destination interface) host`.

The destination IP address **is** what specifies the destination interface.

You cannot ping a raw interface, it must be bound with an IP address - that's what you ping.

> I want to do this so that I can capture packets on host on specific interface specified in ping command.

For packet capturing you'll need to find out which interface the destination IP address in question is bound to.

Comment: How would I find that?? Means which interface is bound to host address?

Comment: I just want to know which interface accepts ping request

Comment: You ping a specific IP address and have that address bound to/associated with a specific interface. Most host OSes have a tool to look up the bindings, e.g. in Windows `ipconfig`. Note that host issues and configurations are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, only if the target has different IP addresses applied to its interfaces.  The only thing an IP packet contains about the destination is the destination address.  If the remote host has different addresses on different interfaces, the packet will be routed towards the particular address.  If the ECHO REQUEST gets to a host configured with that IP address, it will answer.

You can however, on most systems which can have multiple addresses, specify the source address.

On Cisco IOS,  give `ping ip` and answer the prompts (extended commands=y).  On most Unix-derived systems, `ping -I interface`.  See documentation for your system for details.